# Invalid <compatible-screen> line in your AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

While uploading the APK to google playstore as update, I am getting the error like "you included an invalid  line in your AndroidManifest.xml: 500/580"

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml compatible screen tags.

```
<compatible-screens> 
        <!-- all small size screens -->
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- XXHdpi Screen -->
       <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
       <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />

         <!-- XXXHdpi Screen -->
       <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="580" />
       <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="580" />

    </compatible-screens>
```

Could any one have idea on this.

Thanks
in advance.
    Jetti

Comment: `android:screenDensity="580"`... where did you take **580** from? xxxhdpi density is actually **640**.

Comment: Hi, For few devices like Nexus 6, LG G3, S6,.. Google recognizes the density value like android:screenDensity="560". Because we don't have preferred values.

Comment: This is only the density specified by the manufacturer in the `build.prop` configuration file. You can write anything there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it with below code.

```
 <compatible-screens> 
            <!-- all small size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
            <!-- all normal size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

            <!-- all large size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

            <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

            <!-- XXHdpi Screen -->
             <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
             <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />

             <!-- XXXHdpi Screen -->

             <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
             <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" />
             <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />

             <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640" />
             <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
             <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" /> 

        </compatible-screens>
```

Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Screen density tag can only take values such as 'ldpi', 'mdpi' etc. Refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

But here you are passing dpi values such as 480 which is invalid.

Comment: @Puja, Android not only recognize "ldpi", "mdpi",..but also consider the values for android:screenDensity as "480"(XXHDPI), "560" and "640" for XXXHDPI devices.

Answer (score 0):

580 as a screen density is not recognized by google, however 560 is used to support devices like Nexus 6

You can use `<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />`

Also to support normal/large devices to get xxhdpi and xxxhdpi use screenDensity= 480 and 640 respectively